# Text being cut off on div using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck. It's been a while since I've coded CSS. I just need to know the direction I should go to fix this. Right now, the background is not extending all the way down the page on my main wrapper div.

I've tried changing several things, nothing seems to be working. I've tried to use the clearfix, and that didn't seem to make a difference either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  width: 1000px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.logo {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fcc700;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 193px;
}

.logo img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.spacer1 {
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 14px;
}

.search {
  background-color: #f5f4f0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 108px;
}

.menu {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 220px;
  position: relative;
}

.menu img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.square1 {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -780px;
  right: 0;
}

.square2 {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -390px;
  right: 0;
}

.square3 {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.square4 {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 390px;
  right: 0;
}

.square5 {
  background-color: #cdcdcd;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 178px;
  height: 178px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 780px;
  right: 0;
}

.leftcolumn {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 480px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.rightcolumn {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  width: 480px;
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  position: absolute;
  left: 506px;
}

#recentarticles {
  color: #bbbbbb;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fcc700;
  font: 20px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
  line-height: normal;
}

#recentarticlesbody {
  color: #bbbbbb;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
  font: 20px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
  line-height: normal;
}

#recentarticlesbody h1 {
  color: #373737;
  position: relative;
  font: 26px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
}

#recentarticlesbody h2 {
  color: #818181;
  position: relative;
  font: 18px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
}

#recentarticlesbody h1 a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #373737;
  position: relative;
  font: 26px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
}

#recentarticlesbody h1 a:hover,
a:active {
  color: #bbbbbb;
  position: relative;
  font: 26px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
}

#recentarticlesbody p {
  color: #aeaeae;
  position: relative;
  font: 12px "Verdana", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
}

#hotarticles {
  color: #bbbbbb;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 5px solid #fcc700;
  font: 20px "Times New Roman", Serif;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="spacer1"></div>

  <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg"></div>

  <div class="search"></div>

  <div class="menu">
    <div class="square1">
      <a href=""><img src="images/vendorcontacts.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="square2">
      <a href=""><img src="images/tsdocuments.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="square3">
      <a href=""><img src="images/bookmarks.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="square4">
      <a href=""><img src="images/suggestfeat.jpg"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="square5">
      <a href=""><img src="images/news.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- main section -->

  <div class="main">

    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div id="recentarticles">Recent Articles</div>
      </span>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <a href="">
              <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
            </a>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
      <div id="hotarticles">Hot Articles</div>
      </span>
      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

      <div id="recentarticlesbody">
        <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</p>
          <p>18 March, 2018 in
            <font color="000000">Maintenace Notifications</font>
          </p>
      </div>

    </div>


  </div>

</div>

<!-- end main section -->

</div>
```

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2slZ9.jpg)

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the current result and maybe a better description of what the desired result is - we can not replicate your results because we don't have the images you use, and the background color works as I would expect it to.

You have an extra closing `</div>` tag at the end, so your HTML structure could be off.

Comment: @Bricky I checked the code and it appears to be correct. No extra divs, though, I think I might've missed one, so I adjusted that and didn't make a difference.

Comment: @Bricky and I have added the sample link at the bottom.

Comment: Your CSS is really obtuse for what you're trying to accomplish. You shouldn't need to float or position anything to get columns. 

Made some changes [here](https://codepen.io/BrandonKerr/pen/QmmJdj) that you can take a look at

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but how do I make the two columns center, with padding on the left and right (like my example).

Comment: .leftcolumn, .rightcolumn {
  background-color: #FFF;
  margin: auto;
  width: calc(48% - 6px);
  border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
  display: inline-block;
}

I tried this, but it aligns left.

Comment: You can add margin to the columns individually, or you could add some padding to class main `.main{ padding: 0 5px; }` for example

Comment: Thanks so much! I got it! Looks exactly how I wanted it to. I surely do appreciated it!

Answer (score 0):

You had an awful lot of errors in your html code.  I corrected as best I could and changed some colors in your css to better see what's going on.  This looks to be working although you may want to modify further.  In the future, when you are having html problems the first check should be something like the w3 markup service  [W3validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

The errors that I found in your html included:

```
<h2> tags terminated with </p>
reuse of id's - should change these to class
2 stray </span> tags
1 stray </div>
<font> tag use - has been depreciated
no <head> tags, no <title> tag, no lang specified in <html> tag
no alt= on image tags
```

```css
html {
      height: 100%;
    }

    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: blue;
    }

    .wrapper {
      margin: auto;
      width: 1000px;
      min-height: 100%;
      background-color: #f5f4f0;
      overflow: hidden;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .main {
      width: 1000px;
      padding-top: 14px;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: #f5f4f0;
      height: 100vh;
      float: left;
    }

    .clear {
      clear: both;
    }

    .logo {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #fcc700;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 193px;
    }

    .logo img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .spacer1 {
      background-color: #f5f4f0;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 14px;
    }

    .search {
      background-color: #f5f4f0;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 108px;
    }

    .menu {
      background-color: #dbdbdb;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 1000px;
      height: 220px;
      position: relative;
    }

    .menu img {
      max-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      width: auto;
      height: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .square1 {
      background-color: #cdcdcd;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 178px;
      height: 178px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -780px;
      right: 0;
    }

    .square2 {
      background-color: #cdcdcd;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 178px;
      height: 178px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: -390px;
      right: 0;
    }

    .square3 {
      background-color: #cdcdcd;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 178px;
      height: 178px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
    }

    .square4 {
      background-color: #cdcdcd;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 178px;
      height: 178px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 390px;
      right: 0;
    }

    .square5 {
      background-color: #cdcdcd;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 178px;
      height: 178px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 780px;
      right: 0;
    }

    .leftcolumn {
      background-color: #FFF;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 480px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      left: 10px;
     
    }

    .rightcolumn {
      background-color: #FFF;
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      width: 480px;
      border: 2px solid #d7d7d7;
      position: absolute;
      left: 506px;
    }

    #recentarticles {
      color: #bbbbbb;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 13px;
      position: relative;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #fcc700;
      font: 20px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
      line-height: normal;
    }

    #recentarticlesbody {
      color: #bbbbbb;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 13px;
      padding-right: 5px;
      position: relative;
      font: 20px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
      line-height: normal;
    }

    #recentarticlesbody h1 {
      color: #373737;
      position: relative;
      font: 26px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
    }

    #recentarticlesbody h2 {
      color: #818181;
      position: relative;
      font: 18px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
    }

    #recentarticlesbody h1 a:link,
    a:visited {
      color: #373737;
      position: relative;
      font: 26px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
    }

    #recentarticlesbody h1 a:hover,
    a:active {
      color: #bbbbbb;
      position: relative;
      font: 26px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
    }

    #recentarticlesbody p {
      color: #aeaeae;
      position: relative;
      font: 12px "Verdana", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
    }

    #hotarticles {
      color: #bbbbbb;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 13px;
      position: relative;
      border-bottom: 5px solid #fcc700;
      font: 20px "Times New Roman", Serif;
      margin: 1px;
      line-height: normal;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en'>
<head><title>hi</title></head>
<body>




    <div class="wrapper">

      <div class="spacer1"></div>

      <div class="logo"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt='nogo'></div>

      <div class="search"></div>

      <div class="menu">
        <div class="square1">
          <a href=""><img src="images/vendorcontacts.jpg" alt='nogo'></a>
        </div>
        <div class="square2">
          <a href=""><img src="images/tsdocuments.jpg" alt='nogo'></a>
        </div>
        <div class="square3">
          <a href=""><img src="images/bookmarks.jpg" alt='nogo'></a>
        </div>
        <div class="square4">
          <a href=""><img src="images/suggestfeat.jpg" alt='nogo'></a>
        </div>
        <div class="square5">
          <a href=""><img src="images/news.jpg" alt='nogo'></a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- main section -->

      <div class="main">

        <div class="leftcolumn">
          <div id="recentarticles">Recent Articles</div>
          

          <div id="recentarticlesbody0">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <a href="">
                  <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
                </a>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody1">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody2">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody3">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody4">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody5">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody6">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody7">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody8">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody9">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="rightcolumn">
          <div id="hotarticles">Hot Articles</div>
          
          <div id="recentarticlesbody10">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody11">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody12">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody13">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody14">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody15">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody16">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody17">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody18">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
               <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

          <div id="recentarticlesbody19">
            <h1><a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor</a></h1>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi...[]</h2>
              <p>18 March, 2018 in
                <span style="color:pink">Maintenace Notifications</span>
              </p>
          </div>

        </div>


      </div>

    </div>

    

    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah I haven't gotten that far yet, with validating. The title and head tags were in there, but I guess it didn't copy over. I plan on replacing the font tags, just was mocking something up quickly to change the look.

Thanks for the heads up. I did add the doctype and lang tags. Totally forgot about that. And I did find the span tags (I don't know how they got there, I guess my editor did it automatically). What extra div tag am I missing?

Comment: seems at least to me you are making this a lot more complicated than it needs to be.  I would get rid of the absolute positioning. You have a container.  You have a top and bottom. inside the bottom you have a left and right. margin:0 auto, float left float right and you're done

Answer (score -1):

In your .main and .wrapper classes you have the height set to 100vh. Since 1 vh is 1% of the viewport height your main div (and background) will be the height of the users screen. If your page is taller than their screen as soon as they start scrolling down the background will end.

You may be able to just take the "height: 100vh" out to fix the issue or you may have to specify "height: none"

Comment: .wrapper {
 margin: auto;
 width: 1000px;
 min-height: 100%;
 background-color: #f5f4f0; 
 overflow: hidden;
 height: none;
}

.main {
 width: 1000px;
 padding-top: 14px;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f5f4f0;
 float: left;
 height: none;
}

 -- I changed it to this, and that did not fix it.

Comment: Try taking about the height: 100% from the html and body css as well.

Comment: changing the height will not help because the element was absolutely positioned/floated.